# Issue with IEnumerable<TEntity>

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I want to write a common method which returns any model like product, sales,etc. Something like this (.net 3.5; I'm **not** using entity framework)

```
public class ProductRepository<TEntity> : IProduct<TEntity> 
    where TEntity : class
{       
    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetProductList(string Type)
    {
        IEnumerable<Product> fLit = from p in ProductList
                                    select p;

        return fLit;
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the following error

> Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Product>`' to
>   `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TEntity>`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As the compiler says, use a cast.

Comment: I would agree, and am curious, which part of the compiler error is confusing or not clear?

Comment: You can probably drop the `string Type` parameter. You can get a similar information with `typeof(TEntity).FullName`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you have to change design of your Domain, well this is not how Repository Pattern going to implement. First of all You have to have a base class for your Domain Models something simple like below (Of course this is not necessary):

```
public class EntityBase {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}
```

then you must have a generic IRepository interface :

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : EntityBase {
    TEntity FindOne(int id);
}
```

after you implement generic IRepository interface you need to have a concrete Repository class which is inherited from you generic interface, like this :

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : EntityBase {
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;

    public Repository(DbContext dbContext) {
        _dbContext = dbContext;

        _dbSet = _dbContext.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> Entities {
        get { return _dbSet; }
    }

    public TEntity FindOne(int id) {
        return Entities.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == id);
    }
}
```

this is neat, so as you can see here we expect DbContext parameter for Repository class constructor. Also we take the advantage of our entity base's Id property to find what exactly we want.

Well till now you implement a basics of Repository pattern, from now on, you need to create a Repository class for each Domain Entity. let's implement what you've asked here :

```
public class ProductRepository : Repository<Product> {
    public ProductRepository(DbContext dbContext)
        : base(dbContext) {

    }

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetProductList(string Type) {
        IEnumerable<Product> fLit = from p in Entities select p;
        return fLit;
    }
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Do we need the entity framework for this approach? I have added System.Data.Entity namespace, but still its not identifying DbContext and DbSet objects? Am i missing something?

Comment: Yes, you need to add System.Data.Entity reference to your project. Did you install NuGet extension for Visual Studio ?

Comment: Yes, I have added the System.Data.Entity namespace. But the framework is .net 3.5, i cannot use .net 4.0 in the framework.

Comment: What's your application type ? WinForm, Silverlight, Web Applicatoin ? which one ?

Comment: Actually you can use ObjectContext instead of DbContext, DbContext is a wrapper for ObjectContext and use in EF CodeFirst.

Comment: Im designing the framework to support any type of front end. It interacts heavily with SharePoint 2010, so I want to stick with .net 3.5. The above mentioned code is in Data access layer.

Comment: As I said, you are able to use ObjectContext instead of DbContext.

Answer (score 2):

The error is pretty clear: a TEntity is not a Product.  In .Net 4.0 you could use covariance to fix this, but in .Net 3.5 you may do the following:

1. Change your type constraint from `where TEntity : class` to `where TEntity : Product`.  You are already assuming this in the method, so do this so the compiler can enforce it.
2. Use LINQ to explicitly cast the results to TEntities: `return fLit.Cast<TEntity>();`

Comment: Thank you, the option 1 changes the purpose of the class. Options 2 works fine, but concerned about the type casting.

Comment: Sometimes you do have to type cast. It's like reflection, it can be risky but it does have it's uses!

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 3.5 you cannot cast a generic type like that. So just keep your enumerable as a generic type. Change the line to:

```
IEnumberable<TEntity> flit = from p in PRODUCT LIST select p;
```

Comment: This will only work if `PRODUCT LIST` is also a generic container on `TEntity`.  If the list is actually a container of Products this will just move where the compilation error occurs.

Comment: Of course. Reading the question though, it's likely either generic or a container of models. Former case: fine. Latter, cast as above.